# getJSON Works on Document Load, but not through Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function getQuote successfully populates the quote and author divs with text when the document is ready, but it does not pull a new quote and author on the button click. I tested the button click with an alert function and it works so I'm not sure why the getQuote function has no results.

```
var quote = "", author = "";

function getQuote() {
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(data) {
  quote = data[0].content;
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=quote;
  author = data[0].title;
  document.getElementById("author").innerHTML="- " + author;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getQuote();
  $("#button").click(getQuote);
});
```

Comment: Your handler doesn't exit anymore

Comment: @SLaks — No. If that was the case then having the handler throw an alert wouldn't work.

Comment: _"but it does not pull a new quote and author on the button click"_ Are results from request at `click` different from results at `.ready()`?

Comment: Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/jaredgblumer/pen/wGyoBL?editors=1010

Comment: @JaredBlumer codepen http://codepen.io/jaredgblumer/pen/wGyoBL?editors=1010 appears to return expected results

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a cache issue. Problem solved:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
         cache: false
})
```